# Synchronous task not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I am learning threading these days and got confused between creating a synchronous and asynchronous task.I have written a piece of code and it does not work.Can someone give me hint on what is wrong here.

I know it might be a simple question but will really help me in getting the concept.

**What I want**- Sync task 1 should give data only after sync task 2 and sync task 3 is asynchronous.

Also,I want to do it via task and not thread if someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var syncTask1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {


            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
                Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "1");
        });
        var syncTask2 = new Task(() =>
        {


            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "2");

            }


        });
        syncTask2.Start();

        var syncTask3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {


            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)

            Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "3");
        });


      //  syncTask.RunSynchronously();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: All those tasks are asynchronous, and all of them will execute on a different thread from your main thread. If you want tasks to have a sequence, make them have a sequence - e.g. `await`, `ContinueWith`. Finally, `RunSynchronously` doesn't do what you think it does (I agree the name is confusing) - read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Sir,I do not want to use async and await becasue i do not have required .net framework version to support .Also,its because I am learning and want to know any other method.

Comment: If you have `Task`, you also have `await`. Both require the same .NET version, `await` is just a compiler thing - you can use the Async Targetting Pack to "backport" `await` to .NET 4.0. If you still want to avoid `await` (a very bad idea, especially when you don't know what you're doing), `ContinueWith` *is* that other method - one natively supported in 4.0, and the primary method of dealing with any asynchronous workflows on tasks without `await`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not synchronous and asynchronous tasks. You can call (or wait) task synchronously or asynchronously, but task is the same.

If you want to wait task synchronously, you should simply do:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
        Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "1");
});

t.Wait(); // waiting task synchronously
```

If you want to wait task asynchronously:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
        Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "1");
});

await t; // waiting task asynchronously
```

but in this case you should mark your method as `async` - 
([async await usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx))

In you example - to wait first after second and third, you should do:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var syncTask2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
            Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "2");
    });

    syncTask2.Wait();// wait for second task finishing synchronously          

    var syncTask3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
            Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "3");
    });

    syncTask3.Wait(); // wait for third task finishing synchronously after second

    var syncTask1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
            Console.WriteLine(ctr.ToString() + "1");
    });

    syncTask1.Wait(); // wait for third task finishing synchronously after second and third

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks Sir.Just one question.Task.waitall(synctask2,syncTask3) means Pgm waits for syncTask2 and SyncTask3 to complete.But how does it ensure syncTask3 runs after syncTask2 ? Is it becasue of sequence we initiated  synctask3 after synctask2 or becasue we have written syncTask3 after SyncTask2 in Task.waitall(SyncTask2,syncTAsk3 ?

Comment: @vic90, Do you want the second task to complete firstly, then third and then first?

Comment: Yes Sir.It will help me in understanding the flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.i got the point now..Wait will wait the main therad until task calling wait gets finishes.For asynchronoius,normal startnew will do the trick.thanks again

Comment: Sir,it gives error on executing"Error 2:Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable" ,any pointers?

Comment: @vic90, you are right, its my mistake, see main method - Wait() is used in another place

Comment: That's not a synchronous call. That's just a synchronous wait for the result of the asynchronous task. If the task was truly executing on the same thread (as in e.g. a Windows Forms synchronization context), the `Wait` would result in a deadlock. This distinction is *very* important, and one of the things people get wrong all the time.